# Put Firebase and AlertDialog into separate classes

Tags: android

I'm making a shopping list app. I'd like to separate Firebase and AlertDialog into separate classes (i.e. Firebase.class and AlertDialog.class). I've read all the answers here and tried numerous solutions but my app crashes every time if I make the separation (it's working good when everything is in the same class). I'd appreciate any help. Below is my code.

Edited: Below this code is my last try, there are MainActivity, Firebase and DialogAlert class as well as the output. Note that I'm totally in the woods by now.

```
**MainActivity.java**

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editTextShoppingListName;
    Button buttonAddShoppingList;
    ListView listViewShoppingLists;
    List<ShoppingList> shoppingLists;
    DatabaseReference databaseShoppingLists;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        databaseShoppingLists = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("shoppingLists");
        editTextShoppingListName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextShoppingListName);
        listViewShoppingLists = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewShoppingLists);
        buttonAddShoppingList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddShoppingList);
        shoppingLists = new ArrayList<>();

        buttonAddShoppingList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addShoppingList();
            }
        });

        listViewShoppingLists.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                ShoppingList shoppingList = shoppingLists.get(i);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShoppingListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.SHOPPINGLIST_ID, shoppingList.getShoppingListId());
                intent.putExtra(Constants.SHOPPINGLIST_NAME, shoppingList.getShoppingListName());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        listViewShoppingLists.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                ShoppingList shoppingList = shoppingLists.get(i);
                showUpdateDeleteDialog(shoppingList.getShoppingListId(), shoppingList.getShoppingListName());
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void showUpdateDeleteDialog(final String shoppingListId, String shoppingListName) {
        AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_dialog, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText editTextShoppingListName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextShoppingListName);
        final Button buttonUpdateShoppingList = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdateShoppingList);
        final Button buttonDeleteShoppingList = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDeleteShoppingList);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle(shoppingListName);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        buttonUpdateShoppingList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = editTextShoppingListName.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                    updateShoppingList(shoppingListId, name);
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        buttonDeleteShoppingList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deleteShoppingList(shoppingListId);
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean updateShoppingList(String id, String name) {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("shoppingLists").child(id);
        ShoppingList shoppingList = new ShoppingList(id, name);
        databaseReference.setValue(shoppingList);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.shopping_list_updated, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    private boolean deleteShoppingList(String id) {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("shoppingLists").child(id);
        databaseReference.removeValue();
        DatabaseReference databaseReferenceItems = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("items").child(id);
        databaseReferenceItems.removeValue();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.shopping_list_deleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseShoppingLists.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                shoppingLists.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    ShoppingList shoppingList = postSnapshot.getValue(ShoppingList.class);
                    shoppingLists.add(shoppingList);
                }
                ListOfShoppingLists shoppingListAdapter = new ListOfShoppingLists(MainActivity.this, shoppingLists);
                listViewShoppingLists.setAdapter(shoppingListAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void addShoppingList() {
        String name = editTextShoppingListName.getText().toString().trim();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
            String id = databaseShoppingLists.push().getKey();
            ShoppingList shoppingList = new ShoppingList(id, name);
            databaseShoppingLists.child(id).setValue(shoppingList);
            editTextShoppingListName.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.shopping_list_added, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.shopping_list_enter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    }

**ShoppingListActivity.java**

    public class ShoppingListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button buttonAddItem;
    EditText editTextItemName;
    TextView textViewShoppingList;
    ListView listViewItems;
    DatabaseReference databaseItems;
    List<Item> items;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping_list);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        databaseItems = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("items").child(intent.getStringExtra(Constants.SHOPPINGLIST_ID));
        buttonAddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddItem);
        editTextItemName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextShoppingListName);
        textViewShoppingList = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewShoppingList);
        listViewItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewItems);
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        textViewShoppingList.setText(intent.getStringExtra(Constants.SHOPPINGLIST_NAME));
        buttonAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveItem();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        databaseItems.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                items.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Item item = postSnapshot.getValue(Item.class);
                    items.add(item);
                }
                ListOfItems listOfItemsAdapter = new ListOfItems(ShoppingListActivity.this, items);
                listViewItems.setAdapter(listOfItemsAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void saveItem() {
        String trackName = editTextItemName.getText().toString().trim();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(trackName)) {
            String id  = databaseItems.push().getKey();
            Item item = new Item(id, trackName);
            databaseItems.child(id).setValue(item);
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.item_saved, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            editTextItemName.setText("");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.item_enter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    }

MainActivity:
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editTextShoppingListName;
    Button buttonAddShoppingList;
    ListView listViewShoppingLists;
    List<ShoppingList> shoppingLists;
    DatabaseReference databaseShoppingLists;
    com.example.nemanja.execomshoplist.AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Firebase firebase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        databaseShoppingLists = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("shoppingLists");
        editTextShoppingListName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextShoppingListName);
        listViewShoppingLists = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewShoppingLists);
        buttonAddShoppingList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddShoppingList);
        shoppingLists = new ArrayList<>();

        buttonAddShoppingList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                firebase.addShoppingList();
            }
        });

        listViewShoppingLists.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                ShoppingList shoppingList = shoppingLists.get(i);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ShoppingListActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Constants.SHOPPINGLIST_ID, shoppingList.getShoppingListId());
                intent.putExtra(Constants.SHOPPINGLIST_NAME, shoppingList.getShoppingListName());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        listViewShoppingLists.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                ShoppingList shoppingList = shoppingLists.get(i);
                alertDialog.showUpdateDeleteDialog(shoppingList.getShoppingListId(), shoppingList.getShoppingListName());
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}

AlertDialog:
public class AlertDialog extends android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog{


    protected AlertDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    private Firebase firebase;

    void showUpdateDeleteDialog(final String shoppingListId, String shoppingListName) {
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_dialog, null);
        dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

        final EditText editTextShoppingListName = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextShoppingListName);
        final Button buttonUpdateShoppingList = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonUpdateShoppingList);
        final Button buttonDeleteShoppingList = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDeleteShoppingList);

        dialogBuilder.setTitle(shoppingListName);
        final android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        buttonUpdateShoppingList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String name = editTextShoppingListName.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
                    firebase.updateShoppingList(shoppingListId, name);
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });

        buttonDeleteShoppingList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                firebase.deleteShoppingList(shoppingListId);
                alertDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

}

Firebase:
public class Firebase {

    private EditText editTextShoppingListName;
    private ListView listViewShoppingLists;
    private List<ShoppingList> shoppingLists;
    private DatabaseReference databaseShoppingLists;
    Context context;

    public Firebase(EditText editTextShoppingListName, Button buttonAddShoppingList, ListView listViewShoppingLists, List<ShoppingList>
            shoppingLists, DatabaseReference databaseShoppingLists, Context context) {
        this.editTextShoppingListName = editTextShoppingListName;
        this.listViewShoppingLists = listViewShoppingLists;
        this.shoppingLists = shoppingLists;
        this.databaseShoppingLists = databaseShoppingLists;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean updateShoppingList(String id, String name) {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("shoppingLists").child(id);
        ShoppingList shoppingList = new ShoppingList(id, name);
        databaseReference.setValue(shoppingList);
        // Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.shopping_list_updated, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    public boolean deleteShoppingList(String id) {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("shoppingLists").child(id);
        databaseReference.removeValue();
        DatabaseReference databaseReferenceItems = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("items").child(id);
        databaseReferenceItems.removeValue();
        // Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.shopping_list_deleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    public void AddValueEventListener() {

    databaseShoppingLists.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            shoppingLists.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ShoppingList shoppingList = postSnapshot.getValue(ShoppingList.class);
                shoppingLists.add(shoppingList);
            }
            ListOfShoppingLists shoppingListAdapter = new ListOfShoppingLists(context, shoppingLists);
            listViewShoppingLists.setAdapter(shoppingListAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}
    public void addShoppingList() {
        String name = editTextShoppingListName.getText().toString().trim();
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {
            String id = databaseShoppingLists.push().getKey();
            ShoppingList shoppingList = new ShoppingList(id, name);
            databaseShoppingLists.child(id).setValue(shoppingList);
            editTextShoppingListName.setText("");
            // Toast.makeText(this, R.string.shopping_list_added, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Toast.makeText(this, R.string.shopping_list_enter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

Android Monitor:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
on a null object reference   MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:44)                                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)                                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230                                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: What error do you get? share your error log

Comment: I edited the post. It would be easy if there were just 2 classes but I'm totally lost in this situation when 3 classes have to communicate to each other.

Comment: You want to show Dialog? which is in separate class??

Comment: Yes. I need to show this AlertDialog which I want to be in separate class. I also need to have Firebase in separate class and not in my MainActivity.java.

Comment: Then try using DialogFragment , your custom dialogs and in separate classes

Comment: I can help you with the code , if you ask

Comment: Well I would be very grateful if you would make this code work.

Comment: Its a large code, i wont be able to do this, what i can do this is to share the code of dialogFragment with you

Comment: That would be great! And could you show me how to call Firebase from this separate class? It's not too much code for Firebase but it's complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here Try this

```
public class Dialog extends DialogFragment {


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_rooms,container,false);
    getDialog().setTitle("Smart Room");
    getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);


    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getDialog().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON,R.drawable.logo);
 }


}
```

And in your firebase class

First get the activity context as

```
Activity activity;
```

And in constructor of firebase us this

```
this.activity=context;
```

And then use below code to call fragment

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog ();
        dialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.CustomDialog);
        dialog .show(activity.getFragmentManager(), "example");
```

IF you have to call it from activity simply

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog ();                       
dialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL,R.style.CustomDialog);
dialog .show(getFragmentManager(), "example");
```

Comment: It gives me error in the constructor: 
        this.activity = context; And one more question. How to call DialogFragment in my MainActivity?

Comment: Error is:public class Firebase {
    Activity activity;
    public Firebase(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = context; // this is underlined - Cannot resolve symbol context
    }
} And it says ''Cannot resolve DbHelper"

Comment: You can use, this.activity=(Activity) context;

Comment: Now it's:public class Firebase {
    Activity activity;
    public Firebase(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = (Activity)context;
    }
} but context is underlined. Maybe to make Context context?

Comment: First in class make Acitivty activity; then in constructor try activity=context;

Comment: It's ok when I put it this way:Activity activity;

    public Firebase(Activity activity, Activity context) {
        this.activity = context;
    }

Comment: No, simply use activity=context or activity=(Activity) context; in your constructor

Comment: If my answer helped you, dont forget to accept the answer and rate it up

Comment: It's ok now. I just don't now what to do with DbHelper, it cannot resolve symbol

Comment: I couldn't separate Dialog but I managed to separate Firebase based on your answer! Thank you man! Kudos!

Comment: Glad I was able to help you :)